# PowerBi Matrix issue

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I want to create **Requirement 1 **- a Matrix visual where I have Date column which contain Week wise data. I want to display Week wise in same matrix. I have 2 more columns called Benchmark and criteria, which have static values.

[image]

**Requirement 2 :** is to add status column in same matrix which will display values for current week only.
It should be Dyanamic. i.e New Week Data is added then status should be for New week.

Please help. Thank you.

For **Requirement 1 **: I want to prepare Matrix which display Weekwise data in separate columns for each week. Benchmark should display once and not for each week.

**Requirement 2 :**  Please refer problem description **Requirement 2